# How to obtain regex matched string 's file path?

Tags: c#, regex, streamreader, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I have successfully regex matched multiple string from a folder with txt.files with "streamreader" but i also need to obtain the matched string's file path.
How am i able to obtain the matched string's file paths?

```
static void abnormalitiescheck()
    {
        int count = 0;

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(@@@@@)");
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(txtpath);

        Console.WriteLine("No" + "\t" + "Name and location of file" + "\t" + "||" +"    " + "Abnormal Text Detected");
        Console.WriteLine("=" + "\t" + "=========================" + "\t" + "||" + "  " + "=======================");

        foreach (string files in Directory.GetFiles(txtpath, "*.txt"))
        {            
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(files))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {                       
                    Match match = regex.Match(line);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {                                    
                            count++;
                            Console.WriteLine(count +   "\t\t\t\t\t" + match.Value + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If possible , i want to have output of the  strings's file path as well.
For e.g.,

```
C:/..../email_4.txt 
C:/..../email_7.txt
C:/..../email_8.txt
C:/..../email_9.txt
```

Comment: @Emma desired output would be the regex matched string's file path, it is stated in the post

Comment: @Emma but ijust want to have the matched string file path . I currently have 10 txtfile and i have matched 4 of the string from 4 of 10 txt file . Now what i want is the 4 of 10 txt file path to be displayed

Comment: @Emma thats the problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have the `DirectoryInfo`, you could get the [FullName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.fullname?view=netframework-4.8) property.

You also have the filename called `files`. To get the name and location of the file, you could use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8)

Your updated code could look like:

```
Console.WriteLine(count + "\t" + Path.Combine(di.FullName , Path.GetFileName(files)) + "\t" + match.Value + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that we might just want to maybe match some `.txt` files. If that might be the case, let's start with a simple expression that would collect everything from the start of our input strings up to `.txt`, then we add `.txt` as a right boundary:

```
^(.+?)(.txt)$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vezmV4/1)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^(.+?)(.txt)$";
        string input = @"C:/..../email_4.txt
C:/..../email_7.txt
C:/..../email_8.txt
C:/..../email_9.txt";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but i just want to have the matched string file path . I currently have 10 txtfile and i have matched 4 of the string from 4 of 10 txt file . Now what i want is the 4 of 10 txt file path to be displayed